# Rails controller lifecycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to know a little about the object lifecyle in rails, can I count on new instance per request?, Is it true to say that each web request creates a new controller instance?(by default)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on a fresh controller instance per request.

[RailsGuides:](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

> When your application receives a request, the routing will determine
>   which controller and action to run, then Rails creates an instance of
>   that controller and runs the method with the same name as the action.